# HTML agility pack ignore input slash

Tags: javascript, html, html-agility-pack

I have tried all answers to solve this but it didn't work for me..
code is like

```
 HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("link");
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("meta");
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
    HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["input"] = HtmlElementFlag.Empty;
html.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
        html.load(file);
         var ETagTable = html.CreateElement("table");
        ETagTable.InnerHtml = ChangedTagE_Str; 

        /* where changedtage_str = <tr>
        <th>Reference:</th>
        <td><input type="text" id="e.reference" size="30" maxlength="32" value="" /></td>
        </tr>*/
```

in innerHTML is gives input as `<input type="text" id="e.crm_reference" size="30" maxlength="32" value="">`

I want `<input type="text" id="e.crm_reference" size="30" maxlength="32" value="" />`

any solution please?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @GauthamanSahadevan I need `<input type="text" id="e.crm_reference" size="30" maxlength="32" value="" />` input tag with closing end

Comment: I wrote it directly after method name.. isn't it correct? @derloopkat

Comment: doesn't even compile. I see "html.load(file);" in your code. This question needs to be edited.

Comment: file is just a path of file..code is working perfectly but it doesnot give output as I want @derloopkat

Comment: I'd like to know what exactly is the document because this CreateElement() method is creating a table **somewhere** into the html document. Just wanted to check that the result is a valid html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set OptionWriteEmptyNodes to true, modify the html in the document and parse back the resulting html by calling LoadHtml().

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
html.Load("page.htm");
html.DocumentNode.Element("html").Element("body").InnerHtml = "<input type=\"text\" />";
html.LoadHtml(html.DocumentNode.OuterHtml); //Reload the document
```

What Gauthaman suggested works if you're loading an external html by using **Load()** or **LoadHtml()** method but it doesn't when inserting new elements or setting **innerHTML** property.

What we can do is tricking Agility to reload the document.

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
html.LoadHtml("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>ttt</title></head><body></body></html>");
var ETagTable = html.CreateElement("table");
html.DocumentNode.Element("html").Element("body").AppendChild(ETagTable);
ETagTable.InnerHtml = "<tr><th>Reference:</th><td><input type=\"text\" size=\"30\""
    +"maxlength=\"32\" value=\"\" /></td></tr>";
html.LoadHtml(html.DocumentNode.OuterHtml); //<-- Reload the document
Console.WriteLine(html.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
```

Comment: Hey there..sorry for late reply..can I do `html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='abc']/div/table").innerHTML = "..."` directly?

Comment: I've tested the above code with latest version of Agility and worked. But I don't know exactly what you're running because you don't publish your html file. If the html is malformed (which is quite common) or you've made other changes that could be the cause.

Comment: Small question..my html is like `<html>..<body><div id="abc"><table><tr><td></td></tr></table><div>some tags</div></div>....</body></html>`..I want to replace table with id abc of parent with new string..in ur case u r appending..please suggest me..

Comment: var abc = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='abc']");
            var table = abc.SelectSingleNode("./table");
            abc.ReplaceChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode("replace table by this html"), table);

Comment: Thanks..it solved..I will ask if need any help again )

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the below code

Edit - please check the write now

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
HtmlNode nodeDiv = doc.CreateElement("div");
nodeDiv.InnerHtml = "<table><tr><th>Reference:</th></tr><tr><td><input type='text' id='e.crm_reference' size='30' maxlength='32' value='' /></td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: I have tried all those as I have written in code snippet ..still it doesnot work